# How do you "bypass" mouse up?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, mouseevent

I am trying to make it so that when a user clicks down, this happens.

In order,

> Does something. (Not being specific, this isn't the important part.)
>
> Mouse up is triggered.

Using: angular, html, css.
Not using: jQuery

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attach two event listeners, one while the user has the mouse pressed down `mousedown`. Once the user lets go the `mouseup` event is triggered. All mouse event listeners are passed an `event` object you can use to get information about the event ie: mouse x, and y positions.one of the methods available is [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) this will stop the browser doing what it usually wants to do. Example: `cmd/ctrl + s` will cause the browser to save the html page. `preventDefault` will stop this.

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown' function (event) {
    // Do something
})
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
})
```

**To address OP comment:**

```
var noMouseUp = true
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  if (noMouseUp) {
      // do something
      noMouseUp = false
  }
})
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
 if (!noMouseUp) {
    noMouseUp = true
 }
```

})

Comment: While this may solve OP's problem, why not elaborate a little on the solution? Would make for great reading for people with the same problem...

Comment: Nice. Now people searching for the same problem will find this more easily.

Comment: I tried adding this in, but it didn't do what I would like it to do. To elaborate a little more, I've created a virtual keyboard that is meant to be used on a touchscreen. When the user clicks a key, it has to wait for "mouseup" before being able to click another key. I am perfectly capable of using the keyboard and consciously removing my fingers quickly so I can type the next character. What I am afraid of is, a user clicking 2 key and not removing their first finger from the first key. This results in the second key not returning the character because of clicking "two points."

Comment: @abejdaniels added a second section to answer your question specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Use `events.preventDefault();` in the mouseup callback.

Use, right after, `event.stopPropagation();` to avoid the event passing to other layered elements.

```
bypassed_element.onclick = function(event){

      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
};
```

Comment: `$scope.insertString = function(letter) {
     //$scope.name = $scope.name + letter;
     $scope.name = [$scope.name.slice(0,$scope.cursorPosVal),letter,$scope.name.slice($scope.cursorPosVal)].join('');
     console.log($scope.name);
     setTimeout(function(){ setCaretPosition("inputBox", $scope.cursorPosVal); }, 5);
    };` If this is my code, would I wrap it with the .onclick = ?